# How to fill rows of a PySpark Dataframe by summing values from the previous row and the current row?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following, simplified PySpark input Dataframe:

```
Category    Time    Stock-level    Stock-change
apple       1       4              null
apple       2       null           -2
apple       3       null           5
banana      1       12             null
banana      2       null           4
orange      1       1              null
orange      2       null           -7
```

I want for each `Category`, ordered ascending by `Time` to have the current row's `Stock-level` value filled with the `Stock-level` of the previous row + the `Stock-change` of the row itself. More clear:

```
Stock-level[row n] = Stock-level[row n-1] + Stock-change[row n]
```

The output Dataframe should look like this:

```
Category    Time    Stock-level    Stock-change
apple       1       4              null
apple       2       2              -2
apple       3       7              5
banana      1       12             null
banana      2       16             4
orange      1       1              null
orange      2       -6             -7
```

I know of Pyspark Window functions, which seem useful for this, but I cannot find an example that solves this particular type of problem, where values of the current and previous row are added up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can take a rolling sum of `coalesce(level, change)`

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('new_stock_level', 
               func.sum(func.coalesce('stock_level', 'stock_change')).
               over(wd.partitionBy('cat').orderBy('time').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
               ). \
    show()

# +------+----+-----------+------------+---------------+
# |   cat|time|stock_level|stock_change|new_stock_level|
# +------+----+-----------+------------+---------------+
# | apple|   1|          4|        null|              4|
# | apple|   2|       null|          -2|              2|
# | apple|   3|       null|           5|              7|
# |banana|   1|         12|        null|             12|
# |banana|   2|       null|           4|             16|
# |orange|   1|          1|        null|              1|
# |orange|   2|       null|          -7|             -6|
# +------+----+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the -sys.maxsize? and not for example -1?

Comment: @Peter - `-sys.maxsize` is to mimic `unbounded preceding` -- you want to sum all values till the current row to get the result for the current row e.g. `4+(-2)+5 = 7` as the last row for `apple`

Comment: With modern versions of Spark you should use `rowsBetween(wn.unboundedPreceding, wn.currentRow)`. @Peter because the transformation happens in parallel on each row, not sequentially. Therefore, you have to perform a cumulative sum from the start of the partition each time. With -1 you will only sum with the *original* value on the previous line.